# Proper way to increase Windows 8.1 client volume size after iSCSI target increase

Tags: windows, iscsi, windows-8.1, diskmanagement

We increased the size of our iSCSI target from 500GB to 1TB. The only computer that connects to this target is a Windows 8.1 workstation. We would like the workstation's volume to increase and take advantage of the full 1TB available to it:

[image]

I considered converting the disk to a Dynamic Disk and Extending it. Maybe that's the right approach; maybe not. I read on various blog posts and forums that you must use a partition tool like GParted to extend the volume, but I don't know if this applies to iSCSI targets.

I tried right-clicking on `K:` and clicking Expand as esckes suggested in the comment below, but the maximum size is the existing size. Doesn't the disk have to be a dynamic disk to do this?

[image]

What is the most appropriate way to extend Disk 1 to use all the available space **without losing existing** data on Disk 1?

Comment: Just right click on K and use "Extend", there is nothing iscsi specific.

Comment: The maximum space is the free space you can add.

Comment: You can extend volumes on basic disks as long as the space is continuous (as it is in your case). However converting to dynamic does not hurt either on enterprise volumes.

Comment: Well don't I feel silly. I just need to click Next then Finish. I was confused by the UI as I thought the last field was the new size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have expanded your iSCSI target, you can just expand/extend existing drives with that new space.

You do not need to convert to dynamic drive as Windows already sees the extra space on the existing drive, therefore you can extend it with little wait time.

Windows 7 and higher makes it very easy to expand without losing any data.

I strongly suggest you avoid SPANNING. If a drive failed you loose the entire volume.

Here are a few resources to look at:

Windows Technet:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753058(v=ws.11).aspx#BKMK_WINUI)

BleepingComputer:
[How to Shrink and Extend ...](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/shrink-and-extend-ntfs-volumes-in-windows/?#extend)

And of course a Google search:
https://www.google.com/search?q=Dynamic+Disk+and+Extending+windows+8.1+screen+disk+manager

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question to point out I have already tried to expand, but that doesn't work.

Comment: I assume that you have expanded  your Drive now.  that it only took a few seconds after you clicked **Next then Finish**.

Comment: @Swisher-Sweet  Did you edit or Community Edit. ?  either ways, thanks, just had a slight change to the Google link to make it work again.

Comment: I edited the answer. I appreciate your help.